# Angularjs filtering timestamp INPUT format

Tags: angularjs

I have to present a timestamp in a table that is generated using ng-repeat. One of the fields within each record is a timestamp formatted as `YYMMDDHHmmSS`, meaning last two digits of the year, two digits for the month, two for the day, two for the hour, etc. For instance `160331124536` would represent **March 31, 2016 12:45:36**.

I found a post suggesting the following syntax within the HTML:

```
{{One_Record.Timestamp | date:'medium'}}
```

This replaces the string of digits with a date-time string, but the date and the time are completely wrong.

Is there a way to tell angular what is the contents of the received (initial) string, something like YYMMDD...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in this case you need to write your own filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not pretty yet, but this custom filter will get you going,

```
angular.module('yourAppName').filter('special', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var date = new String(input),
        year = date[0] + date[1],
        month = date[2] + date[3],
        day = date[4] + date[5],
        hour = date[6] + date[7],
        minute = date[8] + date[9],
        seconds = date[10] + date[11];

    var reformattedDate = '20' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds;

    var newDate = new Date(reformattedDate);

    return newDate;
  };
});
```

and then just use it like this,

```
{{ 160331124536 | special | date:'medium' }}
```

Comment: Thank you @ZA. Indeed, not pretty (actually, quite ugly!!!), but it looks it will do the job. Will test it and let you know. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: it will be better if you can reformat the date you are getting (server-side) beforehand, on the server side.  ms works the best.

Comment: Well @ZA, your suggestion works (made a small change though because the DB guy is now returning 4 digits for the year). Many thanks for your solution!!!

Comment: that's great.  tell the db guy to give a better format though :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not exactly that what you wanted, but in my case i solved the problem like this:

HTML:

```
{{getDate(timestamp)}}
```

JS:

```
$scope.getDate = function(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp*1000);
    return date;
};
```

I used a function, which returned the date out of the timestamp.
You can also reformat the date or return for example just the days in this way.
See more about Javascript Date Methods [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside ng-repeat

```
  {{One_Record.Timestamp  |date : 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}
```

Comment: Well.... You solution for the input=20160331140437 (yes, added the two leading digits for the year) gave me: `09/11/2608 05:59`. No the correct date and time.

Comment: Then first you 'll have to convert your milliseconds into date object then use this